# What do the secant and tangent functions have to do with their respective lines?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, terminology

SO I know that a tangent line is a line that touches a curve at one point, and a secant line is a line that touches a curve at TWO points, but what do tangent and secant lines have to do with tangent (tan(x)) and secant (sec(x)) functions?

Answer (score 2):

The names are indeed what they sound like. This image says it all:

[image]

(found at https://www.mathematicalway.com/mathematics/trigonometry/tangent/).

FYI, "tangent" and "secant" come from Latin participles mean "touching" and "cutting", so the tangent line $DE$ glances off the circle whereas the secant line $AE$ cuts across it.